# Moving more rows then selected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this app script that is supposed to move a row if a checkbox to marked or unmarked (to another sheet). I know there is definitely some real cleanup I need todo but when I read thru it all seems like it should work.

Currently if I check a box it moves that row then moves the last row also. Any pointers would help.

I am thinking about re-doing this proper instead of a bunch of if statements. But I do need it to work in the meantime.

> IF: Sheet name XA and column Y = TRUE move to sheet Xb and delete Row
> This is done for 4 possible check boxes

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Working on" && e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Submited Routes");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } else if(sh.getName() == "Submited Routes" && e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Working on");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Working on" && e.range.columnStart == 11 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Missed");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } else if(sh.getName() == "Missed" && e.range.columnStart == 11 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Working on");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }


  // NOT AWARDED AUTOMATED MOVE AND DELTE
  if(sh.getName() == "Submited Routes" && e.range.columnStart == 15 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Not awarded");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } else if(sh.getName() == "Not awarded" && e.range.columnStart == 15 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Submited Routes");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Working on" && e.range.columnStart == 15 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Not awarded");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } else if(sh.getName() == "Not awarded" && e.range.columnStart == 15 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    var numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Working on");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it seems like cleaning your code and getting a temporary solution are two separate things, but you're more likely to get a temporary solution *by* fixing your code.

If I understand your problem correctly, this code should be a good start:

```
function onEdit(e){
   var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();

   // a list of the coordinates of the checkboxes (2d list with each sublist having the sheetname and row, col coordinates)
   var checkboxKey = [['sheetName', 0, 0], ['sheetName', 3, 4]] 
   
   // iterate over all checkboxes, and act if necessary
   for (var i = 0; i < checkboxKey.length; i++){
      if (e.value && (sheetName == checkboxKey[i][0]) && (e.range.rowStart == checkboxKey[i][1]) && (e.range.columnStart == checkboxKey[i][1]){
          // single operation that you're doing up to four times -- I'm not sure that I understand what exactly you want to do here
          var numColumns = e.range.getSheet().getLastColumn();
          var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(checkboxKey[i][0]);
          var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
          sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(trg);
          sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That is a lot better. Is there a way I can just exclude the row or use getActive row on edit because the rows change thru out the day.

Comment: `getActive` will work if you're editing the row you want to move (or some row in relation to it). Otherwise you could have some kind of dynamic input for the row you want to change (a static cell in the sheet, a [script property](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties), or a prompt.) I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean with this comment.

Comment: Here is a example sheet the bottom row explains what rows would take action if checked
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mw049W0AbZfNsfeu6VI4HuW-BETdYhYRmI3eYumVGNI/edit?usp=sharing